# cocos2d-x: sequential action running on multiple sprites

Tags: c++, action, cocos2d-x

i have many sprites and i want to move them in screen sequentially. for example 'A' moves to (x1,y1) place then 'B' goes to (x2,y2). i want to run these actions sequentially means first 'A' finishes it's job then 'B' starts.
i have a function that when i call it, returns a sprite and a place and i should send the sprite to that place. in the move function i have somthing like this:

```
void move(){
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        pair<CCSprite,CCPoint> x=get();
        CCFinitTimeAction* act=CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(DIST/SPEED,x.second);
        x.first->runAction(act)
    }
}
```

now how can i make a delay until a motion finishes. i had put this line after runAction but it didn't work:

```
while(!act->isDone());
```

Comment: this for iterates over all your sprites, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `get()` can be called to fetch sprite 2 right when sprite 1 finishes, you could implement this using a callback that calls `get()` and starts the next sprite's movement. For this, you need to create a callback method. Assuming you are doing this in a scene, the following code should do it

```
void YourSceneClass::move() {
    moveNext();
}

void YourSceneClass::moveNext() {
    pair<CCSprite,CCPoint> x=get();
    CCFinitTimeAction* move=CCMoveTo::actionWithDuration(DIST/SPEED,x.second);
    CCCallFunc* startNext=CCCallFunc::create( this,
        callfunc_selector(YourSceneClass::moveNext) );
    CCSequence* act=CCSequence::create(move, startNext, NULL);
    x.first->runAction(act);
}
```

With this code in your scene, you should be able to call move and have the first sprite start moving with the second one moving after that and so on. To make it stop, you have to add an appropriate condition in `moveNext()`.